# Can't connect two VGA monitors to graphic card

Tags: multiple-monitors

My hardware is :

```
MB - MSI Mortar B550 
CPU AMD Ryzen 5950X
Graphic card : RTX 3060 Gaming 12 Gb
```

I try to connect two old monitors with only VGA connectors to HDMI port using such cable
on the picture
There is no signal on the both monitors when i start my PC. If only one monitor connected  - everything is ok. I swapped cables,monitors - no signal on the both. Then i inserted one more graphic card and connected second monitor to them - no signal on the both .
I checked BIOS - i could'n find suitable option.
Any advices?

[image]

Comment: The RTX 3060 shouldn't have any issues with 2 monitors but that cable looks strange. I wonder if an 'active' converter might work here over a passive (?) one.

Comment: Are you sure the old monitors are still functional?

Comment: Yes, sure. They work  if only one connected .

Comment: How's the power supply? Newish?

Comment: @CanadianLuke, yes . All components are new

Comment: And you tested each cable independently to verify they're at least outputting an image? I know you say you tested with one monitor, but I'm wondering if while it's working, you swapped the cables only.

Comment: Does the cable work on 'different' HDMI ports? Getting an active converter is still the right idea, or a more up to daye display but... that has me curious

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Cables such as the one pictured above CAN'T be used.** You need an actual adapter, a digital-to-analogue converter.

The cable you have is a (almost) SCAM!

It isn't a complete SCAM because it has legit usages for old devices, mostly Windows XP "tablets", that used an HDMI connector *in lieu* of the larger D-SUB (VGA) connector but had no digital outputs whatsoever. They used to come with this sort of cables or shorter plug adapters. But this cables are still being sold more than a decade past its due date WITHOUT any warning about them NOT being fit for the purpose of connecting an actual HDMI output to an old VGA only device, thus fooling too many customers.

You need an [actual active converter](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hdmi%20to%20vga%20converter&crid=20MSIBLVUUC75&sprefix=hdmi%20to%20vga%2Caps%2C192&ref=nb_sb_ss_ts-doa-p_5_11) (examples) and probably better to consider using proper modern monitors with HDMI and DisplayPort inputs. It makes no sense running a new and powerful Nvidia Graphics with old monitors.

Comment: On the other hand, it works with *one* monitor, which is a little strange... unless *one* of the ports has analog support... oh wait...